# Proving a quadratic equation having real and positive solutions

Tags: quadratics

How should I go around on proving the quadratic equation
$$a^2 x^2 +(2ac-b^2)x+c^2=0$$
having real and positive solutions?

I tried to use the fact that if a quadratic equation has real and positive solutions, then the discriminant is greater or equal to 0, and that $\frac{b}{a}<0$ and $\frac{c}{a}>0$.  But I kind of stuck after proving that $\frac{c^2}{a^2}>0$ and that $\frac{c}{a}>0$.

Comment: In your case, you need the coefficient of  $x$ to be $<0$, in addition to the discriminant being positive. That is because the quadratic expression can be written as $a^2(x-x_1)(x-x_2) = a^2x^2 - a^2(x_1 + x_2)x + a^2 x_1x_2$ with $x_1, \, x_2 > 0$.

Comment: Have you tried the case when a = b = c = 1?

Comment: If $2ac-b^2\gt 0$, then the equation does not have any positive solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

This is  a standard high school exercise. You indeed have to  prove that
$$\Delta=(2ac-b^2)^2-4a^2c^2=b^2(b^2-4ac)$$
is positive for the existence of real roots, that the product of these roots is positive (nonzero roots with the same sign) and their sum is also positive (the common sign is also the sign of the sum).

Comment: The [product & sum of a quadratic's roots](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/#vietas-formula-quadratics-easy)